# implementing progress dialog in which the no of images to be downloaded in more than 1

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to show progress dialog at the time images are being downloaded from server. i am able to download the images and implement the progress dialog but my problem is that the progress dialog doesnot get  dismissed and it only shows the last downloaded image.

I am using the following code for that :

```
         public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

    int myProgress;


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image.setImageBitmap(result);
        if(dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
         return;
    }



    protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProfilePageNormalUser.this,
                "Loading...", "Please wait...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... paths) {
        return DownloadFile(imageUrl);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

}
```

and the following for calling these:

```
      new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute(imageUrl);
```

Can anyone tall me what could be the problem
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to call [publishProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) after each image. `publishProgress()` will then call `onProgressUpdate()` on the UI thread.